# c++ string erase does not work for UTF8 string, what library can I use?

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, insert, erase

Program:

```
void foo() {

    string sourceStr = "Tag:贾鑫@VoltDB";
    string insertStr = "XinJia";
    int start = 4;
    int length = 2;

    sourceStr.erase(start, length);
    sourceStr.insert(start, insertStr);
    cout << sourceStr << endl;
}
```

For this program, I want to get output as "Tag:XinJia@VoltDB", but it seems that the std string erase and insert does not work for UTF-8 string.

Is there any boost library that I can use? How should I solve this problem?

---

After talking with others, I realize that there is no standard library that can solve this problem. So I write a function to do my work and would like to share it with others who have this similar problem:

```
std::string overlay_function(const char* sourceStr, size_t sourceLength,
        std::string insertStr, size_t startPos, size_t length) {
    int32_t i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < sourceLength) {
        if ((sourceStr[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
            if (++j == startPos) break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::string result = std::string(sourceStr, i);
    result.append(insertStr);

    bool reached = false;
    j = 0;
    while (i < sourceLength) {
        if ((sourceStr[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
            if (reached) break;
            if (++j == length) reached = true;
        }
        i++;
    }

    result.append(std::string(&sourceStr[i], sourceLength - i));
    return result;
}
```

With this funciton, my program can be:

```
cout << overlay_function(sourceStr, sourceStr.length(), 4+1, 2) << endl;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You might want to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3011082/10077 Some of the answers include library suggestions.

Comment: "There's no UTF-8-aware iterator provided in the standard library". Thanks, that's what I need to know. 
Then I have to write my own function to deal with UTF8 string index.

Comment: I did find a blog post that implements such an iterator. You might want to take a look: http://www.nubaria.com/en/blog/?p=371

Comment: I wrote a function to do this work, have not checked your iterator blog yet. But it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Indices in C++ string are *encoding value indices*, not character (or in your case ideogram) indices. With UTF-8 each character can be composed of more than one encoding unit, and in your case it is so. Find the correct encoding unit index.

Tip 1: I'd use `.substr` and `+` string concatenation for this.

Tip 2: it seems that you can search for the characters `:` and `@`. Note that these encoding units cannot occur in multi-unit UTF-8 character. Check out the methods of `string`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I guess both tips does not work for me, as I am not sure the input string format.

Comment: @xin Note that your condition `!= 0x80` won't work for UTF-8 characters in general, only those of two encoding units (at least I think so, haven't tested!). Instead of assuming things about bit patterns it's simpler and more clear and more robust and more correct to just check if (unsigned) code is `>=0x80`. If so ignore all but one in the run of such values, i.e. use an inner loop to scan forward.