# Write struct to text file gives Korean letters

Tags: c++, struct

The program I'm writing is suppose to ask the user for name, haircolor, age and weight and these are then placed in a struct. The struct is then written to a file 'REGISTER.TXT' among other heroes.

I'm using three separate files of main.cpp, hero.h and hero.cpp where the latter holds the current functions.

** Main Issue: The struct writes korean characters instead of 'A - Z'. This is interesting in this case because I have a totally separate program with the same ofstream-code, the only difference is that the code below is in separate files and the working program is all written in one single file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include "hero.h"

// Struct heroes as parameter to function new_hero
void new_hero(heroes & myHero)
{
heroes strukt;
std::cout << '\n' << "Ange din hjältes namn: ";
std::cin  >> strukt.name;
std::cout << "Din Hero har nu namnet: "
<< strukt.name << std::endl;

std::cout << "Ange hårfärg: ";
std::cin >> strukt.haircolor;
std::cout << "Hårfärgen på din Hero är: "
<< strukt.haircolor << std::endl;

std::cout << '\n';

std::cout << "Ange ålder: ";
std::cin >> strukt.age;
std::cout << "Din Hero's ålder: " << strukt.age
<< std::endl;

std::cout << '\n';

std::cout << "Ange din Hero's vikt: ";
std::cin >> strukt.weight;
std::cout << "Din Hero's vikt är: " << strukt.weight << std::endl;

std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Ange din Hero's kön: ";
std::cin >> strukt.sex;
std::cout << "Din Hero är en: " << strukt.sex << std::endl;

// Writing the heroes name from Struct to REGISTER.TXT
std::ofstream utdata;
utdata.open("/Users/username/C++ projects/Stream IO File/Stream IO 
File/REGISTER.TXT", std::ios::app);
utdata << strukt.name;
utdata.close();
};
```

I can of course include the header-file and main.cpp if anyone asks, but if you can spot something wrong right away that would be great.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Am getting Japanese characters instead :)

Comment: Looks like and utf8 issue. Also I must ask, why using sometimes  `endl` and sometimes `\n` ?

Comment: How do you know they are Korean?

Comment: 1) How are you examining the file? 2) What's the definition of `heroes`? 3) What are your inputs?

Comment: You should add check for results of read and write operations

Comment: Should you be using `wcout`? and L"..." for strings?

Comment: So why does it work in the separate program without issues. Isn't there a simple way of writing a struct to a text file? Liora Haydont I don't know, guess I'm wierd :)

Comment: Korean alphabet is close in size to English alphabet, opposed to Chinese/Japanese, so I doubt that you are randomly hitting on Korean characters.

Comment: Ron, I don't but something tells me that they aren't european 潒敢瑲

Comment: molbdnilo - the definitions is struct heroes
{
    std::string name;
    std::string haircolor;
    int age;
    int weight;
    std::string sex;
    std::vector<int> hobbies;
};

Comment: Ed Heal - Do you mean that I shouldn't use "std::ofstream utdata;" then utdata << strukt.name;?

Comment: Those are actually Chinese characters :P

Comment: Read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/), come back if you still have issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a std::string to a UTF-8 text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011082/how-to-write-a-stdstring-to-a-utf-8-text-file)